# Installing "SQL Server 2000 Client" and "SQL Server 2000 service pack 4"

Tags: sql-server-2000

Installing "SQL Server 2000 Client" and "SQL Server 2000 service pack 4".

I am new to SQL server and want to know if both are different and the exact steps that i need to follow for installation. Please advice.

Comment: Yes, they are both different.  One is the client tools, the other is an update to the server.  Why on earth would you want to install software that is already 12 years old?

Comment: Considering the age of the software you are trying to install, I'm closing this as TL as it is unlikely to be of interest to a very wide audience

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server 2000 Client is the driver, admin and query tools.  The service pack is an update for the tools and the server.

I'd recommend looking at a newer version.  Your options are SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2 and the soon to be released SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Chances are the OP is getting maintenance of a legacy system shoved on them.